# Microservices Architecture - Firefox requires exception to be added for every port

Tags: firefox, spring-boot, microservices

I am working on a distributed web application using Spring Microservices design pattern where individual services are running on different ports like -

```
Product Management - domain:8500

User Management - domain:8501
```

Now If the user calls User Management by opening the URL "domain:8501/some_url" which internally calls Product Management i.e. "domain:8500/some_other_url" and also assume that certificate is self-signed i.e. for the browser, the CA is unknown and hence the exception needs to be manually added in the browser.
In this case, while Chrome works fine, Firefox and IE also probably adds the exception for domain with port and hence for internal call as well it waits internally for the security exception to be added.

As a result, my API calling is failed. Is this a Firefox behaviour or I am doing something wrong?

AJ

Comment: You can definitely improve things, either by using proper signed certificates or (the preferred solution in my eyes) using Nginx or Apache as reverse proxy, which makes all services available on one domain and port. That way you can also do load balancing (which you can't at the moment).

Comment: hi @dunni, Somehow in my case having certificates signed by a trusted CA might not be true always. I think Nginx or reverse proxy may be an option. Let me explore, any pointer how I can use in micro services environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try either using an API gateway or a proxy. You can use Zuul for a proxy. Please go through [Zuul starter](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/).

You can even do some more interesting things by having a proxy. Like:

1. Implementing Security: Implement Validation & Verification as security check over the proxy and can avoid the same over other microservices.
2. Response Handling: You can alter a generic response from your microservices in proxy for the client(Web/Mobile Browser/Mobile App)

Hope this helps.